# Which Saturn IB flights did or did not have hinged SLA panels?

Tags: apollo-program

Up until now, I had thought that petal fairings on all Saturn flights had been removed after an incomplete deployment on Apollo 7. But there's a picture of the Skylab 3 mission of the expended S-IVB with SLA panels still attached. My question is, what Saturn IB missions did and didn't have the hinged SLA panels? All Skylabs I assume had them, but what about ASTP, which required LM-like docking?

Skylab 3 picture in question: https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/sl3-114-1625.jpg

Comment: Apollo 7 was the last of the Saturn-1B launches for the Apollo Moon landing program and I want to say that by that time all 1Bs were already built or being built. Since the SLA connects to the IU (which I presume to be different for 1B and V), I'm guessing all 1B SLAs were of the petal-type. But this is speculation, so not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I can say all Skylab flights did have the hinged SLA panels, but ASTP, which required extraction of the docking adapter, did not, as seen in this photo of extraction here: https://catalog.archives.gov/id/16626788